# GCC -Wimplicit-fallthrough is not warning when I miss [[fallthrough]]

Tags: c++, gcc, switch-statement, gcc-warning

I am using GCC version 8.3 and have a switch statement:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Type : char
{
    Value1 = 'A',
    Value2,
    Value3,
    Value4,
};

int main()
{
    Type t;

    switch(t)
    {
        case Type::Value1:
        case Type::Value2:
        case Type::Value3:
            std::cout << "hw" << std::endl;
        case Type::Value4:
            break;
    }
}
```

I want to be forced to use `[[fallthrough]]` otherwise generate a warning.

I added gcc flags to detect missing enums and implict fallthrough:

```
g++ -o main.cc -O3 -Wswitch-enum -Wimplicit-fallthrough -std=c++1z
```

The new flags have been detected because I now get warnings I'm missing enums. I fixed those but I still receive no warnings about implicit fallthrough.

I've put the code here:

https://godbolt.org/z/rj5sTPWz4

Am I missing something? I was expecting to be warned?

UPDATE:

I changed the code to this:

```
struct Object
{
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    Type t;
    Object o;

    switch(t)
    {
        case Type::Value1:
        case Type::Value2:
        case Type::Value3:
        case Type::Value4:
            o.a = 5;
            break;
    }
}
```

and it still doesn't generate a warning.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's considered fallthrough if you've got no statements in between the labels—that's just multiple case labels on a statement.

Gcc doesn't even warn on

```
    case Type::Value1:
    x++; //real fallthrough here
    case Type::Value2:
    case Type::Value3:
    case Type::Value4:
        break;
```

though (unlike clang), but it does warn on

```
    case Type::Value1:
    x++; //real fallthrough here
    case Type::Value2:
    x++;
    case Type::Value3:
    case Type::Value4:
        break;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/s8Ka84Gq6

so it seems you need both actual fallthrough (on both gcc and clang) and into something that has an effect in order to elicit the warning (on gcc).

Comment: @user997112 That's actual fallthrough and clang is content to warn on that. But as I pointed out, gcc's philosophy seems to be to try and be gentler and not to shout at you for that break-followed fallthrough because it's harmless. Now if you fallthrough from a cout to another cout, even gcc warns.

Comment: I've just added an update based on what you said. It still doesn't generate a warning.

Comment: @user997112 With an actual fallthrough (not just multiple case labels on a statement) into a non-break statement it does: it's shown right in the godbolt link in my answer.

Comment: But surely the point of the warning is to prevent Value1 and Value2 cases from modifying Object's state?

Comment: @user997112 Better think of it as preventing accidental continuation from one case-labeled statement to another. Enforcing that each case label be isolated should not be the goal of the warning. If it were, you'd lose a convenient mechanism for saying `if (t==Type::Value1 || t=Type::Value2 ...) { ... }` with `switch`es. Since multiple case labels on a statement are allowed on both gcc and clang under `-Wimplicit-fallthrough`, you can achieve that effect easily with `case Type::Value1: case Type::Value2: ... { ... }`.

Comment: I tend to use `return` on every line to avoid the problem of break/fallthrough but i wanted to try and avoid this

Answer (score 0):

```
    case Type::Value4:
        break;
```

Because there is just break there, there is no difference, if you fall through or not. Add something there.

```
    case Type::Value3:
        std::cout << "something";
    case Type::Value4:
        std::cout << "actually something else";
        break;
```

Comment: I've just added an update based on what you said. It still doesn't generate a warning.